# Adding another value below the row

Tags: mysql

Hey guys i have did some coding in mysql to add a new line value to a row..

```
SELECT 
babe
FROM
(SELECT 
    concat_ws(' ', 'assword \n') AS babe,

) test;
```

When i did like this i get an output like

`BABE`

`assword` `name`

What i need is an output like

`BABE`

`assword`

`name`(this would be below `assword`)

Is there any mysql functions to do this ??...or can i UPDATE the row ??..

I am a newbie in mysql. Hope you guys can help me out..Thanks in advance..

Comment: why do you add a new line to mysql?you can add a new line when retrive the data.

Comment: Sounds like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement includes a newline character in the `babe` column.  You can confirm this by using the HEX() function to view the character encodings.

For example:

```
SELECT HEX(t.babe)
  FROM ( SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', 'assword \n') AS babe ) t
```

On my system, that Will output:

```
 617373776F7264200A
```

It's easy enough to understand what was returned

```
 a  s  s  w  o  r  d     \n
 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64 20 0A
```

(In the original query, there's an extraneous comma that will prevent the statement from running. Perhaps there was another expression in the SELECT list of the inline view, and that was returning the `'name'` value that's shown in the example output. But we don't see any reference to that in the outer query.

It's not clear why you need the newline character. If you want to return:

```
BABE
-----------
asssword
name
```

That looks like two separate rows to me. But it's valid (but peculiar) to do this:

```
SELECT t.babe
  FROM ( SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', 'assword \nname') AS babe ) t
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q: i just wanted to know how to add a new row below the assword ..if u know please edit the answer**

It's not clear what result you are trying to achieve. The specification, divorced from the context of a use-case, is just bizarre.

**A:** If I had a need to return *two* rows: one row with the literal `'assword'` and another row "below" it with the literal `'name'`, I could do this:

```
  ( SELECT 'assword' AS some_string )
  UNION ALL
  ( SELECT 'name'    AS some_string )
  ORDER BY some_string
```

In this particular case, we can get the ordering we need by a simple reference to the column in the `ORDER BY` clause.

In the more general case, when there isn't a convenient expression for the `ORDER BY` clause, I would add an additional column, and perform a SELECT on the resultset from the UNION ALL operation. In this example, that "extra" column is named `seq`:

```
SELECT t.some_string
  FROM ( SELECT 'assword' AS some_string, 1 AS seq
          UNION ALL SELECT 'name', 2
       ) 
 ORDER BY t.seq
```

As another example:

```
  ( SELECT 'do' AS tone, 1 AS seq )
  UNION ALL ( SELECT 're', 2 )
  UNION ALL ( SELECT 'mi', 3 )
  UNION ALL ( SELECT 'fa', 4 )
  ORDER BY seq
```

I'd only need to add an outer SELECT if I needed a projection operation (for example, to remove the `seq` column from the returned resultset.

```
  SELECT t.tone
    FROM ( SELECT 'do' AS tone, 1 AS seq
           UNION ALL SELECT 're', 2
           UNION ALL SELECT 'mi', 3
           UNION ALL SELECT 'fa', 4
         )
   ORDER BY t.seq
```

Comment: i just wanted to know how to add a new row below the  assword ..if u know please edit the answer